Trace zero of the function implies trace zero of the partial derivative in flat boundary portion
Let $U=B_1(0)\cap \mathbb{R}^n_+$ be the half unit ball lying in the upper space. Suppose $u\in H^2(U)$ and $u=0$ on $\{x_n=0\}$ in the trace sense, I want to show that $\partial_ju=0$ on $\{x_n=0\}$ in the trace sense for $1\leq j\leq n-1.$
The following is my try: By assumption, there is a sequence of smooth function $u_m\in C^\infty(\bar{U})$ that converges to $u$ in $H^2(U)$ and $\int_{B_1(0)\cap \left\{x_n=0\right\}}|u_m(x^\prime,0)|^2dx^\prime\to 0$, so it suffics to show that $\int_{B_1(0)\cap \left\{x_n=0\right\}}|\partial_j u_m(x^\prime,0)|^2dx^\prime\to 0.$ But I have no idea on how to relate these two integrals, can someone help me?
